# What is the lifetime of an Rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, lifetime

In C++, you can't assign a reference to an expression that returns a value.

```
int & ref = 10 + 10; //Error
```

I noticed, however, that you *can* assign a Rvalue to an expression that returns a value:

```
int && Rref = 10 + 10; //This is ok
```

Does the lifetime of `Rref` extend until the end of the scope, or is using `Rref` undefined behavior?

In a slightly more complicated example, let's take a class with a nontrivial constructor and destructor. It manages a pointer to something else.

```
//These are defined somewhere else
struct State; 
State* makeState() noexcept;
void transformState(State*) noexcept;
void cleanState(State*) noexcept;

//Creates a state and cleans up the state at the end
struct Blitz {
    State* state;
    Blitz() { 
        state = makeState(); 
    }
    ~Blitz() { 
        cleanState(state);
    }
};

void dostuff() {
    auto&& myBlitz = Blitz();
    transformState(myBlitz.state);
}
```

In the function `dostuff`, does the standard guarantee that the destructor won't be called until the end of the function?